# Is there a way to create a dynamic newcolumtype?

Tags: tabularx, programming

Is there a way to create a dynamic newcolumtype within e.g. a `\newcommand` such as `\newcolumntype{#1}{m{50pt}}`?

I tried to do something like this :

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter 

\newcount\dyncount
\dyncount =5

\newcommand{\nct}[1]{%
    \expandafter\newcolumntype{#1}{m{50pt}}%
}%

\makeatother


\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\nct{\@Alph\dyncount}
\makeatother

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|E|E|}
    \hline
    Cell E & Cell E \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, you can find tons of posts with e.g. `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`.

Comment: yes you can place essentially any tex construct in a new command. If you tried something and got an error make a small complete test docuemnt and show the error you got.

Comment: Obviously, `\newcolumntype{#1}{...}` is wrong, it has to be `\newcolumntype[1]{<do something with #1>}`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I thought the question was if you could do `\newcommand\foo[1]{\newcolumntype{#1}{m{50pt}}` ... `\foo{Z}`   to define a Z column (which you can)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You could be right. (As usual with code fragments one does not know the interpretation unless one is the author of these fragments... this raises an interesting suspicion. ;-)

Comment: I gave a MWE to illustrate what I am trying to do.

Comment: You are missing at least one expandafter. But what is the purpose of using a counter here?

Comment: Finally there will be a loop iterating `counter` times (the `counter` itself will be set dynamically too) so the result should look like `\newcolumntype{A}{}, \newcolumntype{B}{},...`)